# Existence of a continuous and non-constant function $f: X \to [0,1]$

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ a normal space and $T_1$ that has more than one point. Prove that exist a continuous and non-constant function $f:(X, \mathcal{T}) \to ([0,1], \mathcal{T}_{us})$ .

**My idea** If $X$ has only two points then $X=\{a,b\}$, since $X$ is $T_1$ then $\{a\}$ and $\{b \}$ are closed, and are disjoint. By the Urysohn's Lemma exists a continuos fuction $f:(X, \mathcal{T}) \to ([0,1], \mathcal{T}_{us})$ such that $f(\{a\})=0$ and $f(\{b\})=1$ and $f$ wouldn't be constant.
But I don't know how to do if $X$ is infinite

Comment: Urysohn lemma is valid for any normal space, you don't need it to be finite.

Comment: @Crostul But I need two closed sets, and I don't know how to do

Comment: Just pick two random points $a \neq b$ and apply Urysohn. Recall that singletons are closed.

Comment: @Crostul Ok I understand

Answer (score 1):

$\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are closed (by $T_1$-ness) and disjoint. So Urysohn's lemma applies to these two closed sets (regardless of the size of $X$; it holds for *any* normal space).